# Issue with Rails, haml + javascript on blur for a field objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm trying to do a fairly straightforward select on blur for a particular field box.   I'm not certain why (for my example) I can't simply get the box to change background color on a blur action.

Here is my code:

in the haml html

```
:javascript
  $("person_email").blur(function(){
    $("person_email").css("background-color","#D6D6FF");
  });

<input id="person_email" name="person[email]" size="30" type="text" class="MB_focusable">
```

in the html

```
<script>
   //<![CDATA[
    $("person_email").blur(function(){
    $("person_email").css("background-color","#D6D6FF");
     });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selector is not correct. 
If selector is an id of the element, put `#` before its name and if it is a class, put `.` before its name in the jquery: `$('#person_name').(property)`

Answer (score 0):

You Should add `#` to selector `$("person_email")` => `$("#person_email")`